# Regex obrigatório número(s) e opcional letras

Tags: regex

Eu tenho esse regex para validar, porém não está funcionando da forma correta, ele precisa ser obrigatório número, podendo ser mais de um, e opcional letras. 
`(?:\\d+[a-z]|[a-z]+\\d)[a-z\\d]*`

Essa é obrigatório 1 letra e 1 número.

Comment: Tente dessa forma: ^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$

Comment: @ViniciusMatos tentei desta forma e ele não fez nenhum tipo de tratamento.

Comment: Tenta esse ^(?:.*\d.{1,2})$ pelo que testei precisa ter ao menos dois números.

Comment: pode ocorrer de ter um número só.

Comment: Tente esta Expressão: `(?:[a-zA-Z]*\d+[a-zA-Z]*)+` para um full match. Exemplo: a1b2c3d4e5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Esta regex valida um conjunto de alfanuméricos mas obriga que haja ao menos **um** número:

```
(?:([a-zA-Z]+|)\\d+([a-zA-Z\\d]+|))
```

Comment: Deu certinho. Obrigado.

Answer (score 5):

Apenas para dar uma outra opção, esta regex obriga que haja pelo menos um número (e o restante dos caracteres podem ser letras ou números):

```
^(?=.*\\d)[a-zA-Z\\d]+$
```

Mas ela não funciona exatamente igual à [resposta do Guilherme](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/333050/112052). Vamos entender as diferenças.

---

### Diferenças entre esta e a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/333050/112052)

*Antes, um pequeno detalhe: o atalho para "dígitos de zero a 9" é `\d` (apenas uma barra invertida). O que acontece é que em várias linguagens a regex é criada como uma string, e dentro de uma string, muitas linguagens usam o caractere `\` para sequências de escape (como o `\n` para quebra de linha, `\t` para tabulação, etc). Por isso, o próprio caractere `\` costuma ser representado por `\\`. Não foi especificado a linguagem que você está usando, mas deve ser esse o caso. De qualquer forma, usarei a forma `\\` apenas para ser consistente com a pergunta (mas dependendo da linguagem/engine, deve ser usado `\d`).*

A principal diferença entre a regex que sugeri e a regex `(?:([a-zA-Z]+|)\\d+([a-zA-Z]+|))` é que esta última nem sempre vai pegar todos os números. Por exemplo, se a string for `a1b2`, a regex só pegará o trecho `a1b`. [Veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/QKXs25/1) que o *match* contém somente `a1b` e o `2` é deixado de fora (na verdade, qualquer coisa que vier depois do `2` não será capturado pela regex).

**Não estou dizendo que esta regex está errada**, até porque [a resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/333050/112052) foi aceita. É apenas para que futuros visitantes que vejam o título **"obrigatório números e opcional letras"** estejam cientes de que a regex não pega todas as letras e números da string (se for usar esta regex para substituição, por exemplo, alguns caracteres ficarão de fora do *match* e não serão substituídos).

---

Outro ponto é se a string **só** pode ter letras e números, ou pode ter outros caracteres (desde que tenha um número). Dá a entender que somente letras e números são aceitos, então é interessante colocar os marcadores `^` (início) e `$` (fim), para delimitar que do início ao fim da string só pode ter o que está na regex.

Além disso, o `(?:` no início significa que o que está dentro dos parênteses não se tornará um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). A menos que você esteja usando os parênteses internos (`([a-zA-Z]+|)`) para capturar o conteúdo do *match* (usando as [referências](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) `\1` ou `$1`) e [não quer que ele "bagunce" a numeração dos grupos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18579103), ele não seria necessário. Na verdade, esse parênteses está em volta da expressão inteira, então ele não parece ser necessário mesmo.

Para terminar, `([a-zA-Z]+|)` significa "uma ou mais ocorrências de uma letra **ou** nada" (o `|` significa "ou" e depois dele não tem nada e já fecha os parênteses). Isso pode ser trocado por `[a-zA-Z]*` ("zero ou mais ocorrências de uma letra", sem os parênteses). Só coloque isso entre parênteses caso queira capturar o *match group* depois.

Resumindo, daria pra simplificar para `[a-zA-Z]*\\d+[a-zA-Z]*`. Ou com os parênteses, caso queira capturar os grupos: `([a-zA-Z]*)\\d+([a-zA-Z]*)`. Ou com os marcadores de início e fim, para garantir que a string inteira tenha somente letras e números: `^([a-zA-Z]*)\\d+([a-zA-Z]*)$`.

Só lembrando que ainda sim há o detalhe de que esta regex deixa o `2` de fora em `a1b2` (obs: se você usar com `^` e `$`, [não vai nem dar *match*](https://regex101.com/r/lG31h6/1) em `a1b2`).

---

#### Voltando a `^(?=.*\\d)[a-zA-Z\\d]+$`

Esta regex usa os marcadores de início (`^`) e fim (`$`) para garantir que a string tenha somente letras e números.

Logo depois do início (`^`) há um [*lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `(?=.*\\d)`. Isso verifica se há algum dígito em alguma posição da string após o início: `.*` significa "zero ou mais caracteres" e em seguida vem o `\\d`, ou seja, o dígito pode estar em qualquer posição da string. O detalhe é que o *lookahead* só "dá uma olhada" sem "sair do lugar". Ou seja, ele vê se tem algum dígito na frente e em seguida volta para onde estava (no caso, no início da string) para verificar o restante da expressão.

E neste caso, o restante da expressão é `[a-zA-Z\\d]+`: uma ou mais ocorrências de letras ou números. Em seguida temos o final da string (`$`).

Ou seja, o *lookahead* garante que há pelo menos um dígito na string. E o restante da expressão garante que teremos somente letras ou números. Com isso, esta regex não deixa nenhum caractere de fora. [Veja aqui ela funcionando](https://regex101.com/r/cPIlji/1) e repare que para a string `a1b2` o `2` não é deixado de fora do *match*.

---

Novamente, não estou dizendo que a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/333050/112052) está errada. Estou apenas dando uma outra alternativa (pois elas não funcionam da mesma maneira e há casos em que isso pode fazer diferença), e cada um avalia o que é melhor para cada caso de uso.